# Different WSDL ASMX,WCF web-services

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, delphi, wsdl

I've got asmx web-service, which is succefully consumed from other clients(.NET,Delphi).

I try come to wcf, and write the same logic at WCF service(basicHttpBinding for interopability). (.net client consume ok, but delphi 7 couldn't call this service).

I start research differences between two services(asmx,wcf) and detect that their wsdl are diffrent:

WSDL asmx:

```
<s:element name="Test">

<s:complexType>

<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>

<s:element name="TestResponse">

<s:complexType>

<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

wsdl of wcf is rather different:

```
<wsdl:operation name="Test"> <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISyncer/Test" style="document"/>

<wsdl:input> <soap:body use="literal"/> </wsdl:input>

<wsdl:output> <soap:body use="literal"/> </wsdl:output>

<wsdl:fault name="ServiceFaultExceptionFault"> <soap:fault name="ServiceFaultExceptionFault" use="literal"/> </wsdl:fault> </wsdl:operation>
```

I think it's a reson why delphi can't generate correct proxy.

Can i config wcf to generate wsdl the same as asmx.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must flatten the WSDL . look at http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2008/07/30/flattening-wsdl-from-wcf-services.aspx and http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/ for information.

Comment: Aravind, now I have next problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173733/wcf-delphi7-method-input-parameters