# WCF Delphi7 method input parameters

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, delphi, wsdl

I've got wcf web-service(basicHttpBinding). Our Delphi7 clients couldn't correct consume it.
I've already flatten the WSDL with WCF extras. Ok. Delphi7 wsdl importer generate proxy correct.

Now I've got the problems with input parameters. they always have default values (empty for strings, 0 for int).

Output values from methods delphi7 gets ok.
for example:

```
        public string Test(string a)
        {
              return "Test"+a;
        }
```

This method always return "Test". My logging system fix that I've got empty a at method, so the problem is correct transfer input parameters.

I can't undersand what's wrong

**EDIT**

proxy:

```
ISyncer = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{D46862B0-BDD3-8B80-35A8-A2AC69F24713}']
    function  Test(const a: String): String; stdcall;
  end;
```

call:

```
Sync:=(dmMain.HTTPRIO1 as ISyncer);
test:=Sync.Test('5555');
```

dmMain.HTTPRIO1 has soLiteralParams  at options:

init:

```
InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(ISyncer), ioLiteral);
```

After call I get exception with message:

```
Error deserializtion message body for operation Test. 
Operation formatter detects ivalid message body. Expecting node type "Element"
with name "Test" and namespace "http://tempuri.org". Actually node type "Element"
with name "xsd:String" and namespace "http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

wsdl fragment:

```
<xsd:element name="Test">
−
<xsd:complexType>
−
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="a" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
−
<xsd:element name="TestResponse">
−
<xsd:complexType>
−
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TestResult" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

**EDIT2**

I research http requests:

.NET

```
<Test> xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><a>5555</a></Test>
```

works correct;

Delph7

```
<Test xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><xsd:a>5555</xsd:a></Test>
```

null input parameter.
The problem is in prefix **xsd**

Comment: not sure what is the cause. Do you get any exceptions? does this service work fine with a .net client (test purpose)?

Comment: No exceptions, Service works fine with .net clients. Input parameters passed correctly

Comment: Please post wsdl and generated proxy class

Comment: I attempted to get web services working between .NET and Delphi 7 about 2 years ago, but found it to be very difficult. Like Darin said below, the issues had to do with the SOAP style and ultimately there were discrepancies that could not be resolved (I remember arrays and custom classes being a nightmare). I wish I had more details for you, but I ended up just manually defining messages to go back and forth via post data. You may not want to spend too much time on this if you have another possible workaround (I wasted a week). Good luck!

Comment: o6tech, thanks for your answer. I don't need arrays, custom classes, just primitive types(int,string). I don't want come back to asmx(it works perfect with delphi7). I would like do it wcf way very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it.
I fixed soap envelope at every service sonsume through event handler OnBeforeExecute of THttpRio.

I fix(remove namespace prefixes) and it works. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Delphi uses RPC/Encoded SOAP whereas WCF uses Document/Literal/Wrapped SOAP. So you need to tell Delphi to use the same format. You could do this by specifying `soLiteralParams` in the `THttpRio.Converter.Options`.

Comment: @Darin: Could you also post the code statment that specifies solietralPrams in the THTTPRIO.converter.Options?